# Wildcard search

Tags: linq, silverlight, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have the following values that I want to look up in my IQueryable data source.

A user can type in values to filter results by in a text box on my Silverlight application, and these inputs are then filtered and sent to my domain service.

The "*" is what a user can enter to do a wild card search, so for example, returning all values where 'TYPE' begins with "P32".

```
List<string> params = new List<string>() { "P32*", "P4552", "P2311" };
```

I then pass this list to a function in my domain service code:

```
IQueryable<MyClass> temp = this.ObjectContext.MyClass.AsQueryable();
temp = temp.Where(c => params.Contains(c.TYPE));
```

This is what I did before I wanted to implement my wildcard search. What would be the cleanest way to do this? I was thinking I'd have to do something like loop through my params list and try Contains on each string (after some more string manipulation) but that way feels so unclean

```
foreach (string x in params)
{
    //look for * wildcard... do some other stuff 
    temp = temp.Where(c=>c.TYPE.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that with your solution a "real" wildcard matching using a wildcard character like `*` won't work. "P32*" for example won't match "P32Whatever", but "P4552" would match "HelloP4552World".
Still thinking about a better solution though... ;)

Comment: I kept that out for simplicity's sake but looking back, I should have whipped something up. Luckily, I can make assumptions that my input will always be 'P' first then 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to completely define how the wildcards work.  Once you do that, you can just fill in the blanks to the following functions:

```
public static class WildcardExtensions
{
    public static bool WildcardContains(this IEnumerable<string> patterns, string value)
    {
        return patterns.Any(pattern => MatchesWildcard(pattern, value));
    }

    private static bool MatchesWildcard(string pattern, string value)
    {
        // implement your pattern matching logic here
    }
}
```

And then your code changes a little:

```
temp = temp.Where(c => params.WildcardContains(c.TYPE));
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Bool is not an iterator interface type" due to the yield. Returning 'IEnumerable<bool>' for WildcardContains won't let me use the "temp = temp.Where(c => params.WildcardContains(c.TYPE));" since it's expecting a single bool. How do I return WildcardContains?

Comment: Opps, that's right, you have to actually just return a bool, not try to return a enumeration of bools.

Comment: Well that fixed it but now when I try to view my temp result in the debugger, it says that "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean WildcardContains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}". Not letting me get anything with this function, even when I explicitly map the results to a class

Comment: Are you trying to use with a database query?  That won't work.  Custom logic like this can only be executed on entities which have already been materialized from the database.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this LINQ on my Entity Framework 4.0 data model. Unfortunately, it looks like this was the best and only solution since every thing else I've tried doesn't work :|